# Simple Framework XML empty string tag

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I want to change the format for an empty element.
I have this code:

```
@Element(name = "UniMed", required = true)
@Namespace(reference = "http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy")
protected String uniMed;
```

And this result:

```
<ns2:DscItem></ns2:DscItem>
```

But the result I'd like is:

```
<ns2:DscItem/ >
```

I've read something [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955902/avoid-empty-element-tag-in-simple-framework-output) about using @Convert but I'm not sure if I can use AnnotationStrategy since I'm already passing a RegistryMatcher to the persister because I want to give dates a specific format.

Comment: Can you use the [`RegistryStrategy`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/RegistryStrategy.html) instead? For an example see [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters).