# Serializing only the values of a Map as an `ElementList` using SimpleXml

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have an object having an attribute of type map, but I want this map to be serialized to a list, containing only the values of this map.

I could do this by other means (for example, by making the map transient, adding a couple of setter/getter returning the values of the map and serializing this list) but I was wondering if there was a way to customize SimpleXml to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

Like in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021119/filter-a-list-before-serialization-using-simplexml/17087774#17087774) is a good idea to implement a [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html).

Here are some aspects:

1. Implement a `Converter` for the object

   1. Retrieve the attribute map
   2. Iterate over it an write it's content to the `OutputNode` **or** write them into a liste and serialize this instead
2. Set `Converter` and `AnnotationStrategy`
3. Serialize

Please see also:

- [How do you access field annotations from a custom Converter with Simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343348/how-do-you-access-field-annotations-from-a-custom-converter-with-simple/14822621#14822621)
- [Parsing differently named elements as a single list using SIMPLE XML library for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068785/parsing-differently-named-elements-as-a-single-list-using-simple-xml-library-for/17086952#17086952) *(Maybe it's already / similar to what you need)*

However, please give us some more informations (like structure of the class and expected output xml).

Comment: I will use your answer to my other question to try to solve my problem. If it is not sufficient, I will come back with further explanation. Thank you.

Comment: In fact the problem is that it seems you need to rewrite the full serialization process. You don't have a way to say "I want to serialize this class exactly like the default settings,except for this part". For the complex classes, rewriting a Converter can take some time.

Comment: You can set a Converter only for the element you need to serialize while the other parts are serialized as default.