# Parsing differently named elements as a single list using SIMPLE XML library for android

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I was wondering if there was anyway to treat col_1,col_2...etc as a list rather than separate elements, using the SIMPLE XML Library for Android. I have been reading a bit about substitutions but I'm still confused.

**Current Format :**

```
<box-headers 
   dataTable="boxscore" 
   col_1="FINAL" 
   col_2="1" 
   col_3="2" 
   col_4="3" 
   col_5="4" 
   col_6="5" 
   col_7="6" 
   col_8="7" 
   col_9="8" 
   col_10="9" 
   col_11="R" 
   col_12="H" 
   col_13="E">
             table
 </box-headers>
```

**I want to be able to parse out the col's as a list of some sort so I can handle any number of cols. Is this possible?**

Comment: Try using a org.simpleframework.xml.convert.Converter, here you can parse an object of any shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *ng* said before: Use a [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html) for this. Simple is brilliant in letting you customize every step of processing (while on the other hand it's possible to let you (de-)serialize even complex structures with some lines of code).

So here's an example:

**A Class that will hold the values from the list:**

```
@Root(name = "example")
@Convert(value = ListConverter.class) // Specify the Converter that's used for this class
public class Example
{
    // This element will be set with the values from 'box-headers' element
    @ElementList(name = "box-headers")
    private List<String> values;


    // This constructor is used to set the values while de-serializing
    // You can also use setters instead
    Example(List<String> values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    //...
}
```

**The `Converter`:**

```
public class ExampleConverter implements Converter<Example>
{
    @Override
    public Example read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // List to insert the 'col_' values

        NodeMap<InputNode> attributes = node.getAttributes(); // All attributes of the node
        Iterator<String> itr = attributes.iterator();

        while( itr.hasNext() ) // Iterate over all attributes
        {
            final String name = itr.next(); // The name of the attribute

            if( name.startsWith("col_") ) // Check if it is a 'col' attribute
            {
                // Insert the value of the 'col_' attribute
                list.add(attributes.get(name).getValue());
            }
        }

        // Return the result - instead of a constructor you can use setter(s) too
        return new Example(list); 
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, Example value) throws Exception
    {
        // TODO: Implement serializing here - only required if you want to serialize too
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
// Serializer, don't forget `AnnotationStrategy` - without it wont work
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());

// Deserialize the object - here the XML is readen from a file, other sources are possible
Example ex = ser.read(Example.class, new File("test.xml"));
```

This example uses only `col_xy` attributes, everything else is dropped. If you need those values too it's easy to implement them. You only have to retrieve them from the `InputNode` and set them into your output.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive example! I'm definitely going to try it this weekend and pick it as a correct answer soon!